# Оборот "не то(,) чтобы"

Tags: пунктуация

Разделятся ли запятой оборот "не то(,) чтобы" в следующих случаях: "Он стал не то(,) чтобы породистой собакой, но красивым псом (—) это точно"?

Answer (score 5):

Нет, не нужна. СОставной сочинительный союз  *не то чтобы...,а (но)*. Запятая ставится перед второй частью союза - **между** однородными членами.

Answer (score 2):

Согласен с [@Ларf](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f). Но если же не вникать в союзы, то объяснить это всё можно так: Подлежащее *"он"*, сказуемые *"стал породистой собакой"* и *"красивым псом"* (но это сказуемое нас не интересует). Между подлежащим и сказуемым запятая никогда не ставится.

---

Теперь насчет тире перед *"это точно"*. Предложение явно из разговорной речи, поэтому тире ставить можно (авторский знак), но, думаю, какими-то четкими правилами его объяснить невозможно.

Comment: О тире - если его не ставить, то нужна ли запятая?